# Can I use sendBeacon to save session duration metric real-time in iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, analytics, sendbeacon

I have integrated the [timeonsite](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) library to store the time users spend on the site in a MySQL database. I'm using the following code to achieve the same.

However, **the data is not getting stored in IOS devices** like iPhone or iPad but works in all other browsers like Chrome, Edge, Opera, Firefox, etc. including Android chrome and firefox.

```js
var Tos;
(function(d, s, id, file) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.onload = function() {

    var config = {
      trackBy: 'seconds',
      callback: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // give your endpoint URL server-side URL
        // that is going to handle your TOS data which is of POST method.
        // Eg. PHP, nodejs or python URL which saves this data to your DB

        // replace with your endpoint URL
        var endPointUrl = 'http://localhost:4500/tos';

        if (data && data.trackingType) {
          if (data.trackingType == 'tos') {
            if (Tos.verifyData(data) != 'valid') {
              console.log('Data abolished!');
              return;
            }
          }

          // make use of sendBeacon if this API is supported by your browser.
          // sendBeacon is experimental technology; it may not work well
          if (navigator && typeof navigator.sendBeacon === 'function') {
            var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
              type: 'application/json'
            });
            navigator.sendBeacon(endPointUrl, blob);
          }

        }
      }
    };

    if (TimeOnSiteTracker) {
      Tos = new TimeOnSiteTracker(config);
    }
  };
  js.src = file;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'TimeOnSiteTracker', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timeonsite/1.2.0/timeonsitetracker.js'));
```

What's the reason for this issue and how to get it resolved?

Comment: What if you use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make the request?

Comment: @double-beep It doesn't work at all. Tested in Chrome and Firefox. **sendBeacon** is the only API designed to capture last moment data traffic; fetch will work mostly fine in normal scenarios but when it comes to **unload events**, which this timeonsite tracker seems to be utilizing, **fetch** just fails silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**NO**"

The reason is given here (taken from https://github.com/saleemkce/timeonsite/issues/9)

---

> "beforeunload" event is not at all supported in IOS devices like
> Iphone, Ipad and mobile safari browser. For these devices alone, we
> have to fallback to "request option/localStorage" for the time being
> by checking Navigator.platform while initiating the tracker. It's a
> win-win situation for us since we can track all devices real-time
> except IOS devices for which we can safely apply "request object
> option" and get the last record later on for now.

---

Real-time API is failing only in IOS devices due to reasons given above but the good thing is, you can use ***request*** option to capture the data in delayed manner. Go through the link once to understand it better.  But the question remains is, if I use ***request*** option for IOS devices, how do I capture real-time for all other browsers in desktop and mobile devices.  The tweak is simple, replace the

```
var config
```

object with this,

```
// checking for IOS based browser or not
var isIOS = (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.platform)) && !window.MSStream;

if (!isIOS) { /* All browsers desktop and mobile except IOS devices */
    var config = {
        // track page by seconds. Default tracking is by milliseconds
        trackBy: 'seconds',

        callback: function(data) { /* callback denotes your data tracking is real-time */
            console.log(data);
            if (data && data.trackingType) {
                if (data.trackingType == 'tos') {
                    if (Tos.verifyData(data) != 'valid') {
                        console.log('Data abolished!');
                        return; 
                    }
                }
                
                // make use of sendBeacon if this API is supported by your browser.
                if (navigator && typeof navigator.sendBeacon === 'function') {
                    data.trasferredWith = 'sendBeacon';
                    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : 'application/json'});
                    navigator.sendBeacon(endPointUrl, blob);
                }
            }
        }
    };

} else { /* For IOS devices only since "beforeunload" event is not supported */
    var config = {
        // track page by seconds. Default tracking is by milliseconds
        trackBy: 'seconds',
    
        request: { /* Presence of request object denotes we're going to use Localstorage */
            url: endPointUrl
        }
    };

}
```

Now, you'll be able to capture data in both ways. Delayed approach(N-1) pageviews for IOS devices and Realtime(N) pageviews for all other browsers in mobile and desktop.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, sendBeacon() Javascript API seems like the key behind this tracker's unrivaled success in terms of **accuracy** and **metric precision** for time-on-site.